# PHP array of days, sort by week

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi I have an array of days from day X to day Y witch var_dumps this:

```
array(7) {

 ["week"]=> string(2) "14"
 ["year"]=> string(4) "2011"
 ["month"]=> string(2) "04"
 ["day"]=> string(2) "09"
 ["sunrise"]=> string(5) "06:32"
 ["sunset"]=> string(5) "20:09"
 ["daylength"]=> string(5) "13:37"
}
```

Now what I want to do is to sort the list of days wich are returned into an accordion with the weeks devided into an list that looks somthing like this

Week 14 - First day of the week

1. Second day of the week
2. Third day of the week
3. Fourth day of the week
4. Fifth day of the week
5. Sixth day of the week
6. Seventh day of the week

Week 15 - First day of the week

1. Second day of the week
2. Third day of the week
3. Fourth day of the week
4. Fifth day of the week
5. Sixth day of the week
6. Seventh day of the week

Week 16 - First day of the week

1. Second day of the week
2. Third day of the week
3. Fourth day of the week
4. Fifth day of the week
5. Sixth day of the week
6. Seventh day of the week

And so on...

All help is appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: Is your _array of arrays_ sorted by date before you attempt to render it? This helps other to answer the question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably want to use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort)

```
function dateSort($a, $b) {
  if($a['year'] != $b['year'])
    return $a['year'] - $b['year'];
  return ($a['week'] == $b['week'])
    ? $a['day'] - $b['day']
    : $a['week'] - $b['week'];
}

usort($array, "dateSort");
```

this should sort your array by year, then week and then day